# Aggregate and apply logic in SQL query

Tags: sql

I have a table which has entries as below:

First entry in the table is a at timestamp 4 and so on..

```
Id   state             timestamp
f    disabled_reason        9
e    enabled                8
d    disabled_reason2       7
c    disabled_reason3       6
b    disabled_reason4       5
a    enabled                4
```

I want to create a column which will have the following logic:
If state is allowed clear the agg_state, else create a pair of state,timestamp and add it in the agg_state column pairs if any exist.

So the output table will look like so:

```
Id   state             timestamp   agg_state
f    disabled_reason        9      (disabled_reason,9)
e    enabled                8
d    disabled_reason2       7      (disabled_reason4,5)
                                   (disabled_reason3,6)
                                   (disabled_reason2,7)
c    disabled_reason3       6      (disabled_reason4,5)
                                   (disabled_reason3,6)
b    disabled_reason4       5      (disabled_reason4,5)
a    enabled                4
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this logic in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the case statement in any SQL-92 compatible database.
You could also use iif in of sql server version 2012 and later:

```
select id
, [state]
, [timestamp]
, case when [state] ='enabled' then '' else '(' + [state] + ', ' + convert(varchar(2),[timestamp]) +')' end as agg_state
, iif([state] ='enabled','', '(' + [state] + ', ' + convert(varchar(2), [timestamp]) +')') as agg_state_v2
 from your_table_name
```